# Java Comparable object equals() and compareTo() returning different results

Tags: java, comparable

In this example I have an `Employee` class that implements `Comparable`, and below is the code for `compareTo()`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee e) {
    if (getName().equals(e.getName())) return 0;
    else if (getPay() < e.getPay()) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
```

When I do `employee1.equals(employee2);` , given that employee1 and 2 have the same name, I am expecting the result to be `true` but it returns false.

But when I did `employee1.compareTo(employee2);` I get the expected result, which is `0`.

Please help me understand the nature of `Comparable`. Thanks!

Comment: What does your `equals` look like?

Comment: How can you ask this question without showing your equals method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compareTo` and `equals` methods are completely unrelated from the perspective of the JVM. It is programmer's duty to make [natural order consistent with equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

If only `compareTo` method is provided for the class `Employee`, the default implementations, derived from `Object` is inherited. You should override `equals` method (together with `hasCode`) to get consistent results.

Answer (score 3):

The point of `Comparable` is to answer the question "If I were to put these things (in this case, `Employee`s) in order, how would I know whether one should be in front of or behind the other?  This means that it is *essential* that the fields you are checking in `compareTo` are exactly the same as those you are checking in `equals`.  This helps to make these two consistent.

It is also important that your `compareTo` method is consistent with itself - in other words, `Math.signum(a.compareTo(b)) = -Math.signum(b.compareTo(a))`.  In your case, two employees with different names and the same pay would always return 1, which means that both of these employees are supposed to come after each other when sorted (which doesn't make sense).

Comment: Good job pointing out the extra problem in the `compareTo()` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide implementation for equals method (that will compare names) in `Employee` otherwise Java uses references equality check, thus two objects with the same name are not equal.